# Wrapping contents of cshtml in pdf viewer of Syncfusion

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, reporting, syncfusion

How can I connect `cshtml` content to `ejs-pdfviewer`, I want to use it as andvantage to be able to print I want I have set into the `PdfViewer` with syncfusion, is it possible?'

Is there any attribute I have to add to enable this functionality, or is there a special way to achieve this in `syncfusion`?

Below is the `cshtml` code :

```
  <ejs-pdfviewer id="container" style="height: 600px"
                   serviceUrl="/api/PdfViewer"
                   documentPath="@Path"

                   enablePrint="true">

    </ejs-pdfviewer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, PDF Viewer do not have support to display the cshtml page directly. However, we can convert the cshml to PDF and then we can load that PDF document in PDF Viewer. We have created the sample for the same and shared in the following location,

https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ViewToPDF_Core1313262793

In the above sample click on ‘ConvertToPDF’ to load the cshtml page in PDF Viewer.

PDF Viewer:
UG link: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/pdfviewer/getting-started/

Reference links for Html to PDF Conversion: 
UG: https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/convert-html-to-pdf/webkit 
KB: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/9779/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-in-azure-using-net-core 
MVC view to PDF (.NET Framework): https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/6024/how-to-convert-mvc-view-to-pdf-using-c-and-vb-net

Note: For converting HTTPS sites, the HTML converter requires OPENSSL libraries to be installed in the machine where the conversion takes place. Please find the below link for reference
https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/convert-html-to-pdf/webkit#openssl

Regards,

Ramya T